# Run PHP script after deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: magento, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a PHP script that generates a local.xml file for Magento with the required database settings and credentials. I need to run this after the application is deployed; however I cannot seem to figure out a way to do so. My understanding is that I need to create a `.config` file inside of a `.ebextensions` directory. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yup, `.ebextensions` are what you are looking for. To see how to bundle the source, take a look at the [sample applications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html). There is a PHP one you can look at as well.

For more info on `.ebextensions`, take a look at [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).

Here's an example of a custom command. This could go in a file called `sample.config` within the `.ebextensions` directory:

```
commands:
    success_command:
        command: echo "this will be ran after launching"
```

Be careful if you copy and paste YAML and double check the format. You can also use JSON which follows the similar format.

Answer (score 8):

Technically Josh is not correct.  According to the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands): the commands section .. "The commands are processed in alphabetical order by name, and they run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted."

The closest I am aware of is the "container_commands" section which "The commands in container_commands are processed in alphabetical order by name. They run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version file has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed."

I don't know of a way to truly run a script post deployment (which is why I was here looking for that answer).

Comment: I missed the "after deployment" part of his question.

Answer (score 6):

Elastic Beanstalk will look files under **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post** directory to run after deployment.

So you can make use of this and do:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/job_after_deploy.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      /var/app/current
      ** run your php script here **
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this seems to run before the environment variables are configured, so don't rely on them being in place for differentiating staging/production in your script.

Comment: Nevermind, solved the environment variable issue by adding `source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` before running the PHP scripts.